# Obtain unknown matrix from eigendecomposition.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, signal-processing, matrix-decomposition

I have doubt with the mathematical tools used in a problem of Signal Analysis:

I have a **complex** observable series $Y(t)$ which is the result of summing two **complex** r.v $X(t)$ (unobservable) and a $\epsilon(t)$ (unobservable).

$$Y(t)=X(t)+\epsilon(t)$$

Assume that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are uncorrelated, and that $\epsilon$ is serially uncorrelated and has constant mean and variance.

I construct a Hankel Matrix of the observed series and then I create a sort of variance-covariance matrix by multiplying the later by its conjugate transpose.

$$ R_Y=\mathcal{Y}\cdot \mathcal{Y^*}=\mathcal{X}\cdot \mathcal{X^*}+\mathcal{E}\cdot \mathcal{E^*}$$

After that I make the eigendecompositon of that matrix and I obtain:

$$U\cdot (\Lambda_X +\sigma^2\cdot I)\cdot U^T$$  Where $U$ is the orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors, $\Lambda_X$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues (in decreasing order) of $\mathcal{X}\cdot \mathcal{X^*}$ and $\sigma^2$ represents the "variance" of $\epsilon$ (under my assumptions $\mathcal{E}\cdot \mathcal{E^*}$ is a diagonal matrix with $\sigma^2$ in its diagonal.

Assume that the matrix $\mathcal{X}\cdot \mathcal{X^*}$ has not full rank, and because of that it has some null eigenvalues.

By the eigendecomposition of $R_Y$ we could select which eigenvalues correspond to the $\mathcal{X}\cdot \mathcal{X^*}$ matrix, (by considering the first $d$ eigenvalues, HOW TO SELECT THE ORDER OF THE MODEL?) and then we can estimate $\sigma^2$.

Knowing $\sigma^2$ we could estimate $R_X=\mathcal{X}\cdot \mathcal{X^*}$.

> **Is there any way to factorize $R_X$ in order to obtain $\mathcal{X}$ and
>   then by the  one-to-one relation between Hankel matrices and Series,
>   obtain $X(t)$? if this is possible, under which additional conditions?
>    If the variables are real-valued, is it the same?**

Comment: Is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02620) the kind of idea you are looking for?

Comment: Indeed it looks very promising, I'll give it a in-detail look. Thanks!